# Jump into .h file instead of .c file when using ctags with vim

Tags: vim, ctags

I want to use Ctags with VIM, and I have use `ctags -R .` to get tags file.
but when I use `CTRL+]` to check out functions, I just jump into a .h file, not .c file, just like:

`void foo();` in foo.h, but what I want is
`void foo(){//CODE HERE}` in foo.c.

Any solutions?Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<C-]>` jumps to the first match.

You could try `g]` or `g<C-]>` to choose from a list instead. See `:help :tselect` and `:help :tjump`.

Assuming ctags picked up the stuff in `foo.c` of course.